# select option text color displayed on dropdown list but not colored in box, this option works in ie 9 but not works in chrome

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/pbvijayk/7bLdg7cg/5/

```css
option.red
{
  color: #cc0000;
}
```

```html
<select name="color">
  <option class="red">Red</option>
  <option >White</option>
  <option >Blue</option>
  <option >Green</option>
</select>
```

please run the code in `ie9` and `chrome`.
color of the text displayed in `ie9` correctly color will appear in both dropdown and dropdown box.
but in chrome text color displayed in dropdown list but not displayed in box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this one :** 
https://jsfiddle.net/7bLdg7cg/7/

```css
.greenText{ color:green; }

.blueText{ color:blue; }

.redText{ color:red; }
```

```html
<select
    onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className"
    class="greenText">
     <option class="greenText" value="apple" >Apple</option>
    <option class="redText"   value="banana" >Banana</option>
    <option class="blueText" value="grape" >Grape</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works. but While loading it cannot works. this wil works only when changing the value.

Comment: @VijayakumarB it's working for both while `loading` and `onchange`. I think you are missing to add `class` in select while rendering, please check the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7bLdg7cg/7/  I have added the `"greenText"` class for `select` tag

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the style to select not the option like this:

```
<select name="color">
  <option class="red">Red</option>
  <option>White</option>
  <option >Blue</option>
  <option >Green</option>
</select>
<style>
select .red
    {
       color: #cc0000;
    }
</style>
```